# Filter and update point geometry

Tags: r, dplyr, spatial, point, r-sf

I have a large sf point dataset. For any x or y coordinate that ends in 000 I want to randomly add or subtract 1 from it (this is top stop a single point intersecting with multiple grid geometries). Is there a way of filtering and editing the geometry directly to achieve this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
         
Data <- tibble(
    id=c("A00111", "A00112","A00113","A00211","A00212","A00213","A00214","A00311","A00312","A00472"),
    x=c(465000,455248,442525,445248,470825,460855,450433,474000,474000,488000),
    y=c(154897,284740,123000,123125,136000,175001,136600,150070,150070,176000))

sf <- st_as_sf(Data, coords = c("x","y"), crs=27700, na.fail=FALSE)
```

The desired output would look something like this:

```
Output <- tibble(
    id=c("A00111", "A00112","A00113","A00211","A00212","A00213","A00214","A00311","A00312","A00472"),
    x=c(465001,455248,442525,445248,470825,460855,450433,474001,473999,488001),
    y=c(154897,284740,122999,123125,136001,175001,136600,150070,150070,175999))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it `directly with the geometry field in a sf object` you need to operate on the POINT objects. Any sort of loop / `apply` will do

The coordinates are numeric, so just check if the number is exactly divisible by 1000, and update it if not.

```r
set.seed(123)

sf$geometry <- sf::st_sfc(
    lapply(
    sf$geometry
    , function(x) {
      sf::st_point(
        c(
          ifelse(x[1] %% 1000 == 0, x[1] + sample(c(-1, 1), size = 1), x[1])
          , ifelse(x[2] %% 1000 == 0, x[2] + sample(c(-1, 1), size = 1), x[2])
        )
      )
    }
  )
)
```

```r
> sf
Simple feature collection with 10 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 442525 ymin: 122999 xmax: 488001 ymax: 284740
CRS:           NA
id              geometry
1  A00111 POINT (464999 154897)
2  A00112 POINT (455248 284740)
3  A00113 POINT (442525 122999)
4  A00211 POINT (445248 123125)
5  A00212 POINT (470825 135999)
6  A00213 POINT (460855 175001)
7  A00214 POINT (450433 136600)
8  A00311 POINT (474001 150070)
9  A00312 POINT (473999 150070)
10 A00472 POINT (488001 176001)
```

Comment: Just for anyone else who uses this in the future. I added ' %>% st_set_crs(27700)' to @SymbolixAU's answer to set the CRS to match the input data

Answer (score 2):

Update:

We could use `st_coordinates()` function from the `sf` package to extract the coordinates of each point and then add or subtract 1:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

sf %>% 
  st_set_geometry(NULL) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(x = st_coordinates(sf)[, 1],
         y = st_coordinates(sf)[, 2]) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(x,y), ~ifelse(. %% 1000 == 0, . + sample(c(-1, 1), length(.), replace = TRUE), .)))
```

```
       id      x      y
1  A00111 464999 154897
2  A00112 455248 284740
3  A00113 442525 122999
4  A00211 445248 123125
5  A00212 470825 135999
6  A00213 460855 175001
7  A00214 450433 136600
8  A00311 474001 150070
9  A00312 474001 150070
10 A00472 487999 175999
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @TarJae's answer this is a solution to my problem:

```
sf2 <- sf %>% 
    mutate(x = st_coordinates(.)[, 1],
            y = st_coordinates(.)[, 2]) %>% 
    st_drop_geometry() %>%
    mutate(x = ifelse(str_detect(x, "000$"),x+sample(c(-1,1),size=nrow(.),replace=T),x),
            y = ifelse(str_detect(y, "000$"),y+sample(c(-1,1),size=nrow(.),replace=T),y)) %>%
    st_as_sf(., coords = c("x","y"), crs=27700, na.fail=FALSE)
```

However, it still requires dropping the geometry first and then converting back to a `sf` object. Is there a solution that can do the above directly with the geometry field in a `sf` object?